# CSS Dropdown Menu Spacing

Tags: html, css

I have managed to create this navigation menu however the spacing on the menu items is off. Also on the secondary lists I've had to make them wide because of one of the items. Is there a way to get the width to vary depending on the length of the longest item.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<title>Menu</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 

body {
    font-family: "Gill Sans", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}

#nav, #nav ul { /* all lists */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 1;
}

#nav a {
    display: block;
    width: 10em;
}

#nav li { /* all list items */
/* The sum of the next two lines creates the nav bar height*/
    padding-top:12px;
    height: 28px;
    float: left;
    background: #f15a22;
    width: 7em; /* width needed or else Opera goes nuts */
}

#nav li ul { /* second-level lists */
    position: absolute;
    background: #f15a22;
    width: 10em; /* controls width of background colour of second-level list - currently set to width of longest entry */
    left: -999em; /* using left instead of display to hide menus because display: none isn't read by screen readers */
}

#nav li:hover ul, #nav li.sfhover ul { /* lists nested under hovered list items */
    left: auto;
    top: 45px; /* drops the second list below the nav bar so it doesn't cut off the bottom of any text from the main nav*/
}

/*--- from Storm3y's code ---*/
#nav li a {
    color: #f9f7ee;
    background-image:url(images/bullet2.gif);
    background-position:0% 50%; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-left: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav li a:hover {
    background-image:url(images/bulletsolid2.gif);
    background-position:0% 50%; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-left: 16px;
    color: #f9f7ee;
}


</style> 

<script type="text/javascript"><!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--

sfHover = function() {
    var sfEls = document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("LI");
    for (var i=0; i<sfEls.length; i++) {
        sfEls[i].onmouseover=function() {
            this.className+=" sfhover";
        }
        sfEls[i].onmouseout=function() {
            this.className=this.className.replace(new RegExp(" sfhover\\b"), "");
        }
    }
}
if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", sfHover);

//--><!]]></script> 

</head> 
<body> 



<ul id="nav"> 
    <li><a href="#">About</a> 
    </li> 
    <li><a href="#">Teaching</a> 
        <ul> 
            <li><a href="#">Philosophy</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Piano</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Guitar</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Drums</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Theory</a></li> 
        </ul> 
    </li> 
    <li><a href="#">Performing</a> 
        <ul> 
            <li><a href="#">Classical Piano</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Jazz Piano</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">The Ginger Nuts</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">The Legion Of Doom</a></li> 
        </ul>    
    </li>    
    <li><a href="#">Media</a> 
        <ul> 
            <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Audio</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Video</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li> 
        </ul>   
    </li> 
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a> 
    </li> 
    <li><a href="#">Links</a> 
    </li>        
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a> 
    </li> 

    <!-- etc. --> 

</ul> 


</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: When you say the spacing is "off", what *should* it be like? What should the total width of the menu be?

Comment: @thirtydot I think the poster is referring to this phenomenon: http://jsfiddle.net/uNNKd/1/ (hover over Performing)

Comment: @Joseph: My comment was regarding his first sentence, which appears to be talking about the uneven spacing between the text (forget about the dropdowns for this part).

Comment: @thirtydot ah I see... yeah... what is the problem then? XD

Comment: @Joseph is right. There spacing between each item isn't even.

Comment: Here is a screenshot http://shiny.me/share/7t1nh4.png 

Issue 1: The spacing between each item isnt even
Issue 2: I'd like to make the width of each item in the dropdown menu differ depending on how wide the text is rather than a fixed width.

Answer (score 2):

This fixes it.  Haven't tested cross-browser though.  With this method also remove your added width attribute on the ul

http://jsfiddle.net/uNNKd/

```
#nav li li {
    clear: both;
    width: auto;
}
```

EDIT

```
#nav li li {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
}
```

That will also work.

Comment: Here is a screenshot http://shiny.me/share/7t1nh4.png 

Issue 1: The spacing between each item isnt even
Issue 2: I'd like to make the width of each item in the dropdown menu differ depending on how wide the text is rather than a fixed width.

Comment: @Ged rats... sorry... I have to go... you can have a look at my edits to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uNNKd/2/. they are denoted by "EDIT".

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/TMrpA/2/

::EDIT::

Here is the CSS Code:

```
body {
    font-family: "Gill Sans", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}

#nav, #nav ul { /* all lists */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 1;
}

#nav a {
    display: block;
}

#nav li { /* all list items */
/* The sum of the next two lines creates the nav bar height*/
    padding:0 20px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height:40px;
    float: left;
    background: #f15a22;
    position:relative;
}

#nav li li {
    float:none;
}

#nav li ul { /* second-level lists */
    position: absolute;
    background: #f15a22;
    width: 10em; /* controls width of background colour of second-level list - currently set to width of longest entry */
    left: -999em; /* using left instead of display to hide menus because display: none isn't read by screen readers */
}

#nav li:hover ul, #nav li.sfhover ul { /* lists nested under hovered list items */
    left: 0;
    top: 40px; /* drops the second list below the nav bar so it doesn't cut off the bottom of any text from the main nav*/
}

/*--- from Storm3y's code ---*/
#nav li a {
    color: #f9f7ee;
    background-image:url(images/bullet2.gif);
    background-position:0% 50%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav li a:hover {
    background-image:url(images/bulletsolid2.gif);
    background-position:0% 50%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    color: #f9f7ee;
}
```

Comment: Fixed the alignment on the second level menu, here is the second version: http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/TMrpA/2/   ... now everything is properly aligned and spaced according to the size of the content of the li tag.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard You're Totally right, i just didn't want to place the full block of CSS since i modified too much. Updated my answer.